# remove only specific text occurrences from string using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, search, string, replace

I have a text file that contains many rows of this sort of thing:

```
/*[17:51:27][1 ms]*/ UPDATE `country` SET `region_id` = '4' WHERE `country_id` = '36';
```

Is there a way that I can use `sed` to remove the comments *only* , so that's everything that starts with a `/*` and ends with a `*/`? This would make the line become:

```
UPDATE `country` SET `region_id` = '4' WHERE `country_id` = '36';
```

I know how to use `sed` to remove an entire line that starts with something, in the example of a text file with SQL in it it would likely be a hash symbol `#`.

Comment: with perl: `perl -ple 's;/\*.*?\*/;;g'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `sed` matches in a `greedy` manner, there is always the possibility that text past the end of the comment will be matched instead of the preceding real end-of-comment marker, eg. as in a quoted string which contains "*/".
This cannot be handled by `sed` in a simple manner, but you can work around it. Here is one such method: using single-character placeholder for the two-character end delimiter. Using hex value `\x01` as the stand-in characters is safe (ie. won't clash with existing text), as it does not exist in normal text.

```
sed "\|^/\*.*\*/|{ s|\*/|\x01|; s|.*\x01|| }" "$file"
```

`perl`, on the other hand, can optionally handle `lazy` matching (and a lot more).  As already mentioned by *Prince John Wesley* in the comments, here is the *lazy* `perl` equivalent.

```
perl -ple 's|/\*.*?\*/||g' "$file"
```

Comment: The `perl` example worked, many thanks. Using Perl and writing the output to a new file I done this: `perl -ple 's|/\*.*?\*/||g' "txt/crmpicco.txt" > text/new_crmpicco.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
sed 's@/\*[^/]*\*/@@'
```

Unfortunately it may has difficulties with comments with `/` inside.

May be it will be useful two variants together: to be sure that absolutely all comments are removed:

```
sed 's@/\*[^/]*\*/@@;s@/\*[^*]*\*/@@;'
```